# Design of programmable scaling amplifier as a project for undergrad

Tags: operational-amplifier, circuit-design, scaling

I am building a custom microscope, PhD in biomedical engineering. I would like to have a scaling amplifier, with programmable offset and gain, that takes 0..10V signal X (from [piezo element](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=9862)) and turns it into output -1..1V Y signal (into [galvo mirror](https://www.thorlabs.com/newgrouppage9.cfm?objectgroup_id=3770)) such that `Y=A*(X-B)` where A~0.1-0.5 and B~-1..+1V are adjustable within 2-3 digits. In fact, currently we use A=0.18, offset B=+0.119

The frequency bandwidth should be around 1kHz or higher. The input signal is usually a sawtooth with 1Hz repetition rate. Input impedance should be > 10kOhm, devices outputs into 20kOhm impedance. The delay between input and output should be as short as possible, but 1ms is OK. I think we can tolerate output noise of 0.5-1mV.

Currently we are using [rather expensive 1MHz scaling amp](https://www.thinksrs.com/products/sim983.html), so I want a copy of that with lower quality and much lower price tag. The problem is that we'll need roughly 4-5 of these, at around $1000 a piece. I feel like there is a way to make these devices 10x cheaper.

**Is that a feasible project for an EE undergrad**? I have access professor with much more EE experience than I, for double-checking the final design.

I am considering custom PCB as a solution, or something arduino-based for programmable part.

Comment: Do you know the impedance of the 0..10 source and the load on the -1..1?  Also 3 digits of adjustment/precision is possible.  However, 3 digits of accuracy is beyond the tolerances of regular electronics and can only be done with calibration.  Have you ruled out 16b USB IO? Is there a latency requirement?

Comment: @scorpdaddy re: accuracy. In effect i will do the calibration during alignment. I don't care if device says "B=0.001" but outputs "B=0.005" as long as these numbers are stable over 12 hours, does that make sense?

Comment: Can you be clearer about what A can be and what B can be numerically. Also, is your input signal DC biased such that signal minus B doesn't go negative? What sort of noise output is acceptable for the design and how stable do the offsets and gain need to be drift wise and against temperature.

Comment: @Andyaka thanks for the questions, I added more details. The temperature we can assume to be stable ~RT.

Comment: As currently written, you state that the bandwidth should be 100Hz or higher, and the input to output delay should be of order a microsecond.  Are these both correct? Because they don't seem to fit together.

Comment: @JackB corrected. I ran a simulation and i am OK with 1ms delay, so i guess bandwidth of 1kHz is good cutoff.

Comment: Is this for galvo scanning - are you using the offset and gain to set your image center and size?  You'll need a higher bandwidth than you think.

Comment: @DDuck yes, galvo, but not for confocal, but for light-sheet imaging similar to https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/801688v2

Comment: Have you looked at devices such as https://www.analog.com/media/en/technical-documentation/data-sheets/AD5160.pdf

Answer (score 0):

For signal fidelity (SNR), here are concerns

(1) plan on using a steel box, unless you can guarantee no magnetic fields (only steel handles the 60Hertz power and rectifier surge peak fields)

(2) plan on a Ground Plane; I'd default to 4" by 4" area, plus Power Supply; plan on a steel metallic strip between Power Supply and your analog circuits.

(3) assuming a goal of 0.1 millivolt PeakPeak random + deterministic "noise", with half of that for the Random, in 100Hertz bandwidth, the OpAmp noise density is

50uVPP / [ 6.2 sigma * sqrt(100Hertz) ] = 50uV/62

or

about 800 nanoVolt noise Density.

(4) assuming the output stage is gain-of-10, you are allowed 80 nanoVolt noise Density 
referred-to-input; that is total noise contributors of 400,000 ohms.

(5) to not be burdened by 1/F noise, the 1/F noise plot corner needs to be 50Hz or lower

(6) If this is knob-controlled, then use 10-turn pots with verniers.

If this is computer-controlled, then consider CMOS 10-bit or 12-bit multiplying DACs or DigiPots.

(7) Topology: do the math up front, followed by Gain_of_10X amplifier including a Low Pass Filter to set the noise (random and deterministic) floor.

(8) plan on +- 15 volt supplies, so life is easy. You only need about 1 watt total power, so the Ground plane easily removes heat. Maybe as low as 0.1 watt.

(9) stability over 12 hours: have heat paths from the Ground Plane (metal mounting posts that contact the Steel case and contact the Ground Plane, with metal screws). The thermal time constant of 1 cubic meter of copper is 11,400 seconds. The thermal time constant of 0.1 cubic meter (4") is 100X faster at 114 seconds. Having a central metal mounting post speeds that up by (2*2) to 32 seconds. That's probably acceptable.

(10) pick a good opamp: ensure it is spec'd by a plot for 1/F noise (I may have gone overboard on the achievable noise floor; your call); ensure opamp handles +- 15 volt rails (IMHO)

As with any free suggests, your mileage may vary.

(11) black brick power supplies (switching Regulators) will be a problem.
You want to avoid Ground Loops (charges such as from the black_brick that **MUST** find a return path).